# How to replace a <ul> inside a div by its div id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you replace a `<ul>` inside a div by using the div's id in jQuery,

```
<div id="example">
    <ul>
        Content To Be Replaced...........
    <ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your desired end result?

Comment: use $("#example").html("your text");

Comment: Please post desired output as well.

Comment: `document.querySelector('#example ul').textContent="bla";`
No jQuery, simple semantic syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("#example ul").text('Content to replace');
```

You can select the div with the ID selector `#`.  A space is used as an descendant selector, and `.text` changes the text content.  You could also use `.html` to replace HTML content.

Answer (score 4):

Simply do:

```
$("#example ul").html('New Content');
```

Comment: Are you aware that jQuery's `.html` uses the browser's `.innerHTML` function, which forces the browser to re-parse the entire DOM?
It would be slightly faster to use `$("#example ul")[0].innerHTML = 'New Content';`, [instead](http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-js-dom).

Comment: @Cerbrus : In most of the cases vanila JS is going to be faster than jQuery. OP has asked for a jQuery solution & got one which works. It seems like you are saying that no one should use jQuery?

Comment: I'm saying that it's very inefficient to use jQuery if one's going to do a lot of dom manipulation.
Some speed can be achieved by using a "hybrid" like I suggested, instead, with barely any difference in the code.
I mean, if someone _wants_ to use jQuery, power to them, but I think on a site like this, a alternative option should also be accepted, instead of being stomped down for no apparent reason.

Comment: You are more than welcome to express your opinion. But you are not supposed to down vote an answer if you think it is inefficient, especially when performance is not a factor!

Answer (score 1):

I presume you mean something like this?

```
$('#example ul').html('new content');
```

Comment: Are you aware that jQuery's `.html` uses the browser's `.innerHTML` function, which forces the browser to re-parse the entire DOM?
It would be slightly faster to use `$("#example ul")[0].innerHTML = 'New Content';`, [instead](http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-js-dom).

Answer (score -1):

Absolutely no jQuery is needed:

```
var div = document.getElementById("example");
div.firstChild.nextSibling.textContent="bla";​ //div
//   textnode ->   ul   -> text
```

This can be compacted to:

```
document.getElementById("example").firstChild.nextSibling.textContent="bla";​
//                div     -->      textnode -->   ul  --> text
```

Yes, it is more code than jQuery, but it's also [a **lot** faster.](http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-js-dom).

You could even use:

```
document.querySelector('#example ul').textContent="bla";
```

Still 4-5 times as fast as jQuery, but using very similar, semantic syntax. No need to drop native JS because it's "hard" or anything.

Comment: Okay, if you are going to downvote me, at least tell me why this is a incorrect answer.