# Replacing one div with another according to a value

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have 2 different card designs and I want them to change if a value is higher or lower than 20.

I tried using   document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = "whatever";  but it only changes text.

```html
    <body>
    <div id="div1">This is div 1</div>
        <div id="div2">this is div2</div>
    </body>
```

```js
 <script>
    
    if(data[i].value > 20)
    
   //*replace div1 with div2*
    
    else if(data[i].value < 20)
    
    *replace div1 with div2*
    </script>
```

Comment: what is the purpose of replacing elements while you can assign an (id / class) to your element and do things based on (id / class).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace a <ul> inside a div by its div id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841738/how-to-replace-a-ul-inside-a-div-by-its-div-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show/hide divs:

```js
function showHideDiv(value) {
      let div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
      let div2 = document.getElementById('div2');

      if (value > 20) {
        div1.style.display="none";
        div2.style.display="block";
      } else if (value < 20) {
        div1.style.display="block";
        div2.style.display="none";
      }
    }

    showHideDiv(30)

    setTimeout(function() {
      showHideDiv(10)

    }, 2000)
```

```html
 <div id="div1">This is div 1</div>
    <div id="div2">this is div2</div>
```

To reposition divs:

Here's a reusable function to help illustrate how it's done. If you look at the snippet, it will show both results - the second coming 2 seconds after the first.

Essentially, you need to use this syntax:

```
    theParentContainer.insertBefore(firstDiv, secondDiv);
```

where `theParentContainer` is the parent of both `divs`, `firstDiv` is the div you want to go first, and `secondDiv` is the element to go after the first.

```js
function moveDiv(value) {
  let div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
  let div2 = document.getElementById('div2');

  if (value > 20) {
    div2.parentNode.insertBefore(div2, div1);

  } else if (value < 20) {

    div2.parentNode.insertBefore(div1, div2);
  }
}

moveDiv(30)

setTimeout(function() {
  moveDiv(10)

}, 2000)
```

```html
<div id="div1">This is div 1</div>
<div id="div2">this is div2</div>
```

Comment: Can i use this while making the unused div hidden?

Comment: I thought you meant replace as in move 1 where the other was. Did you mean make one visible and the other hidden?

Comment: Yes,i should have been clearer while asking

Comment: @EdiTheHigh - it's updated. The answer is simple. I made a function out of it to help illustrate

Comment: thank you so much!!
both of these functions will help me out in the future

Answer (score 0):

Try using the hidden attribute. For example:

```
<body>
<div id="div1" [hidden]="data[i].value > 20">This is div 1</div>
<div id="div2" [hidden]="data[i].value < 20">this is div2</div>
</body>
```

Comment: is this angular syntax? `[hidden]`

Comment: It's a HTML property but can be used with Angular Framework.